# Blocktrans correctly written in django template

Tags: django, translation, django-templates, django-i18n

I want my django template variables were possible to translate. I used for this purpose {% blocktrans %}.

Is this code is correct and can be optimized. I mean to write better? The loop or something like that.

```
{% for obj in objects %}
    {% blocktrans with obj.user as user and obj.country as country and obj.b_day as b_day %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user }}</td>
        <td>{{ country }}</td>
        <td>{{ b_day }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endblocktrans %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Where the results ok?

Comment: It works ok. I was wondering if can be write better.

Comment: Since you are asking is because you don't like something in your code. What it is? Personally I don't like having too many html tags inside a translation

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I suspect your code don't work properly. Anyway the simple `{% trans %}` tag looks much better:

```
{% for obj in objects %}
    <tr>
        <td>{% trans obj.user %}</td>
        <td>{% trans obj.country %}</td>
        <td>{% trans obj.b_day %}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```